# SSH tunnel to enable connection to postgres

Tags: c#, postgresql, ssh, openssh

My Postgres server is in a network inaccessible from my computer, so we use SSH tunneling to access it using HeidiSQL.

I want to connect to it from my C# code, so I tried to run `ssh -L 3307:dbhost:22` to create the tunnel, however, the command outputs the list of parameters as if the command syntax was wrong.

My local PC uses Windows 11 and my SSH config file (~.ssh\config) is like this:

```
Host dbhost
    HostName 11.11.11.11
    User jnunes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    ForwardAgent yes
```

With the config above I could connect to the postgres server using HeidiSQL with these settings:

**Settings tab**

- Hostname/IP: 127.0.0.1
- Port: 5432

**SSH tunnel tab**

- SSH executable: ssh.exe
- SSH host + port: dbhost 22
- Local port: 3307

But I could not use the ssh.exe command on Windows to create the tunnel for any software in need to connect to Postgres.

What am I missing?

Comment: 1) This *...in a network inaccessible from my computer, ...* is not true as you can SSH to it. 2) This *With the config above I could connect to the postgres server using HeidiSQL ...* and this *But I could not use the ssh.exe command on Windows to create the tunnel for any software in need to connect to Postgres.* contradict each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you want to connect to your server:

```
ssh dbhost
```

Then you want a localforward (from the server's point of view) of the psql port 5432.

```
ssh dbhost -L5432:localhost:5432
```

Then there should be the Port 5432 visible on your client PC.
Now you can connect per psql on your client:

```
psql -h localhost
```